# HighCharts - Logarithmic X Axis malfunction

Tags: highcharts

Whenever I change the x axis of an existing chart from linear to logarithmic, the chart doesn't scale in the same manner that it does when the Y axis is changed. To be clear, the axis does indeed change from linear to logarithmic, but the Y axis scale does not adjust and appears that it cannot be adjusted to the new settings.

I think that this may be a problem with HighCharts.

The fiddle demonstrating the problem is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfoxworth/rLf7P/). Note that the command that I am using to change the axis is :

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({  type: "logarithmic"  });
```

I may need to include something in that command, but maybe my approach to the problem is too linear and I need to rescale my view (that was supposed to be humorous).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Highcharts, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2117). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Remember me if this gets addressed soon